# Spring Doc 2.2.0 and WebMvcConfigurer issues with timestamps and rendering UI

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, springdoc-openapi-ui

Spring Boot 3.0.4
Spring Doc 2.2.0

I am having issues rendering OffsetDateTime "eventStart": 1647302400.000000000

To solve this I implemented:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper()));
    }

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        return new ObjectMapper()
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .registerModule(module)
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }
```

Now I can render OffsetDateTime correctly:  "eventStart": "2022-03-15T00:00:00Z",

However, this breaks the Swagger UI:
Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.x.y (for example, openapi: 3.1.0).

application.yml

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    # custom path for swagger-ui
    path: /${spring.application.name}.html
  api-docs:
    #custom path for api docs
    path: /docs/api
    version: OPENAPI_3_1
  paths-to-match: /**
  show-actuator: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `@EnableWebMvc`, it solved similar issue for me